# How do I create number of days to go progress bar on django

Tags: python, django, progress-bar, creation

Please I've an App I created, and I'm finding it hard to add progress bar count down for days to go before the user get what they Applied for? I used the formula now - start time / end time - now + now - start time all in days, seems to work pretty well but things get awkward when the month number changes...
Please any help

Answer (score 0):

No need for convoluted formulas. Use [datetime objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and just subtract the current time from the start time. E.g.

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now


class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    @property
    def days_to_go(self):
        time_remaining = self.start_time - now()
        return abs(time_remaining.days)
```

`days_to_go` will now be available in the context object, along with `event_name` and `start_time`

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/) to get a better understanding of working with time in Django.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) for Django's `DateTimeField` model field.